# How can I disconnect my PS3 controller from MotioninJoy/DS3Tool?

Tags: controllers, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I plug my PS3 controller into my PC for two reasons: a) charging, and b) I also have a game that I play that I use my controller for, using MotioninJoy/DS3Tool.

However, I don't know how to to disconnect the controller from MotioninJoy/DS3Tool. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you disconnect:

1. If you open the DS3 window, you will see a menu bar.
2. Click "Profiles"
3. In the bottom, there will be a button saying; "Disconnect"

I hope this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just plug the PS3 controller into the PS3 via the microUSB cable (while the PS3 is on) and hit the PS button, the controller should sync to the PS3 and will no longer be synced to the PC. You'll have to re-pair the controller to the PC (over USB) to use it via bluetooth on the PC again.